# Ajax pass object to dancer module

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, dancer

I have an object called 'contacts' passed through ajax to perl dancer module like:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Contacts/savecontact',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {con: contacts},
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("success");
                }
   });
```

in module

```
any [ 'ajax', 'post'] => '/savecontact' => sub {
    set serializer => 'JSON';
    my $body = request->body;
    ### I need to get each value in objects contact like name, id etc

};
```

I tried to dump `$body`, it comes as `"'con%5Bid%5D=1&con%5Bname%5D=Amy+John&con%5Baddress%5D=test+here'"`

Anyone please help me to get the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Dancer::Plugin::Ajax (which it looks like you are), you can use the `param()` method in your ajax requests as usual.  So, e.g.,

```
my $con = param('con');
```

Based on your example `$body`, I would expect (but don't know for a fact) that `$con` would then be a hash reference with the keys `id`, `name`, and `address`, which could be accessed as normal with `$con->{id}`, etc.

Comment: I have tried my $con = params->{'con'}; it was working. but some time it was not workng. ie, values are not getting some times

Comment: @Futuregeek That's extremely odd. Whatever you do, it should consistently work or consistently not work. If I were in your position, I'd do what sometimes works and then focus on figuring out why it sometimes doesn't.

Comment: yes. That is what I also doing. I couldn't figure our why it is not coming in params. but it is getting in request->body everytime

Comment: When it doesn't work you probably pass on an array as opposed to a hash?